# Organ and Bone Marrow Transplantation?

Tags: bone-biology, organs, immunity, transplantation, surgery

In organ transplantation the transplant is rejected by the body's immune system , but is it possible if along with organ transplant if bone marrow transplantation is carried out from the same donor , then will the Cell Mediated immunity still reject the graft ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mowgli pointed out, a bone marrow transplant involves destroying the patient's own immune system with radiation and, essentially, replacing it with a new one from the bone marrow donor. If you did a double kidney/bone marrow transplant from Alice into Bob, then Bob's new immune system (which is the same as Alice's) would recognize the new kidney from Alice as *self* (because it is) and not attack it. Yay!

The problem is that, to the new immune system, all the rest of **Bob** appears to be non-self and will get attacked. This is called [Graft-versus-host disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graft-versus-host_disease) and is *at least* as serious a problem as organ rejection.

Comment: _"The problem is that, to the new immune system, all the rest of Bob appears to be non-self and will get attacked. This is called Graft-versus-host disease and is at least as serious a problem as organ rejection"_: What do you think of this https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79881/could-bone-marrow-transplants-be-used-to-prevent-tissue-rejection-of-trans-speci as a fix for that, introduce both patient & body donors cells to the pig fetus then transplant it's bone marrow?

Answer (score 2):

Bone marrow [transplant](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/bone-marrow-transplant/about/pac-20384854) requires to first destroy the pre-existing immune system with chemotherapy and/or radiations. So essentially you would not have the first immune system and my guess is that yes, *in theory*, it would work.

However, double-grafting an artificially immunocompromised patient (who clearly suffers from another severe pathology, if they need an organ graft in the first place) would be *extremely* risky as it would exponentially increase the risk and mangnitude of post-operation complications, and I think no surgeon in their right mind would ever take such risk.